# Avoid filter textox in checkbox column in datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one datagrid.The columns header name is binding from one xml file.
Now I need to add filter text box for header template from datagrid.

1. without textbox filter option the datagrid shown as per the below.
   [image]
2. After adding filter text box the datagrid as shown as below

[image]

I don't want to show textbox in first column i.e checkbox column,how to do this?
The xaml code is attached below

```
<UserControl .....>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>


            <DataGridTemplateColumn  x:Key="CustomCheckBoxTemplate">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <CheckBox Name="ColumnHearderCheckBox" IsThreeState="True" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnHeaderCheckBoxMouseButtonDown" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate >

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnCellCheckBoxPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                      AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>


            </DataGridTemplateColumn >

             <ContextMenu x:Key="ColumnHeaderContextMenu"
                FontSize="{Binding PlacementTarget.FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
                        <EventSetter Event= "Click" Handler="OnContextMenuItemClicked" />
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility}" Value="Hidden">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="5,0,0,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
                                <Border x:Name="Border"
                             Padding="2"
                             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                 Path=ActualHeight}" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource=
                                         {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Width="100"  />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

            </Style>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="30,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ContextMenu  x:Key="RowMenu" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"  >
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
            <Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"  IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding PatientStudyList}"  SelectionMode="{Binding SelectionMode, Converter={StaticResource SelectionModeToStringConverter}}"
                  AlternationCount="2" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  BorderThickness="1" 
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unloaded">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataGridUnloadedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderContextMenu}" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />


                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Hi, would be nice to get some feedback whether my answer solved your question (relevant part is mostly in the edit section) or if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the `DataGridColumnHeader.Template` with a new `ControlTemplate`

The `CustomCheckBoxTemplate` is providing a `DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate` as `DataTemplate` which targets the `DataGridColumnHeader.ContentTemplate`. However, your `ControlTemplate` doesn't use the `DataGridColumnHeader.ContentTemplate` internally, so the `HeaderTemplate` part of your `CustomCheckBoxTemplate` will be ignored.

If it works for you, just define the `DataGridColumnHeader.ContentTemplate` instead of the `DataGridColumnHeader.Template` in your style (will behave a little differently).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
    ...
    <!-- Do not define Property="Template" here -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Similar to your ControlTemplate, but the TemplateBinding parts need to be reworked -->
```

Otherwise use the `DataGridColumnHeader.ContentTemplate` inside your `ControlTemplate`.

```
<!-- Old -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource=
                                     {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
<!-- Replace by -->
<ContentPresenter
    Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
```

Didn't test all part, so there might still be errors in my suggestion.

**Edit** Actually, the last part about the `ContentPresenter` doesn't prevent the `txtId` textbox. Here is an idea where the `ControlTemplate` is using `Triggers` to change the visible parts based on the `ContentTemplate` property being set. Note I changed some minor details like the `ColumnDefinition Width` for my testing.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
    <Border x:Name="Border"
     Padding="2"
     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid"
                Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Width="100"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <ContentPresenter
                x:Name="TemplatedContent"
                Visibility="Visible"
                Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TemplatedContent" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LayoutGrid" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```